# position:absolute one of display:table-cell elements causes WebKit to render gap

Tags: css, webkit, css-tables

I'm trying to build a horizontal menu with the last item seperated and positioned right, so that a logo finds place between the last and the second last item.

[image: That's the final result]

Firefox, Opera (Presto) and even the dirty ones from Redmond (9.0+) render it like I would expect. But WebKit (Chrome and Safari both render it the same) takes some space after the second last item where the last item would stay without `position: absolute`.

```
<header>Logo</header>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Statistics</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Data Management</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Market Research</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Web &amp; Apps</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I display the list as `table` and the list items as `table-cell` because I want the left part of the menu (first to second last item, left to the logo) to have a fixed width while the items take the width they need for their contents. Text could change to anything. Till there, everything is alright. But if I give the last item a `display: block; position: absolute`, WebKit renders that gap (white in the example).

[image: Left: non webkit; Right: webkit]

```css
nav ul
{
    display: table;
    background: white; /* that's what you see in webkit */
}

nav ul li
{
    display: table-cell;
}

nav ul li:last-child
{
    display: block; /* "display: none;" works like I would expect */
    position: absolute;
}
```

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3TUk8/).

I'm not sure if it is a bug in WebKit, because absolute positioning an element inside a table might not be default behavior. On the other hand, `display: none` works like I would expect. Shouldn't the space consumption be 0 in both cases?

Does anybody know of a bug in WebKit or has anyone an idea of how to prevent that gap?

Comment: I can't understand why you are forcing an un-ordered list into display:table?  Best to use float, display:inline or display:inline-block.

Comment: @Lowkase: Because I want the menu to scale to the same width, no matter what's the text of the items.

Comment: I understand the problem will still exist, so I guess it is not an option to simply move the background color onto the <li> rather than the <ul>?

Comment: @Martyn0627, unfortunately not. The trouble is, that the layout changes (yes, it's just 2 px, but I cannot accept that... and yes, the doc claims it's normal ;-) ). Only a workaround resulting in exactly the same layout like Joshs does would do the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the penultimate element "Web & Apps" to display `block` instead of `table-cell`:

```css
nav ul li:nth-last-child(2) 
{
    display: block;
}
```

[Display block fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dCmaU/)

Comment: Holy sh*!! If you see it, it's so easy you can't believe and kill your self for not having the idea. Well, not everybody can be a genius I guess. ;-) You ARE a genius graham. Thank you so much!

Comment: Graham tracked that down like a true Columbo fan! Great fix :)

Answer (score 1):

I've pushed this answer on other people, and often got the "flexbox isn't widely supported yet" response.  However, here it goes again.  The reason that Webkit is misbehaving is that within its implementation of `display: table`, the DOM is reserving space for the semantically declared cell.  The easy way to implement this would be to simply break this element out into its own object, much like you'd done with the logo.

***HOWEVER...***
if you want to keep these semantically grouped - And why wouldn't you, they're all content, right? - you can always use the flexbox model to overcome this.

[Here's a fiddle showing its use.](http://jsfiddle.net/3TUk8/6/)

Here's what we change:

```css
nav ul
{
    display: box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    background: white; /* that's what you see in webkit */
    empty-cells: hide;
    table-layout: auto;
}

nav ul li
{
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

Now, your items properly cover the background, as it is no longer treating the last `li` as if it were a true table cell and still within the bounds of the table.  Flexbox provides a flexible layout to fill available space.  Often people see this as a solution for the ["Holy Grail of Layout"](http://hacks.allizom.org/2010/04/the-css-3-flexible-box-model/comment-page-1/) problem, but its use expands way beyond just that.

So, if another "Flexbox isn't widely supported enough" response is incoming, I understand.  But I'll keep proposing it as an answer on every one of these that I come across, because support *is* getting better every day.

Comment: I would use it, and maybe I will someday. But (sorry :-) ) as you said: Currently it's too hot, because I need it for a company website. +1 for your effort and a really great solution for future. If nobody comes with a "bugfix" like `-webkit-be-so-nice-to-give-gap-the-width: 0` (terrible what a jungle they have currently), I will award you the bounty. So, you seem to have good chances ;-). Thank you very much!

Comment: If you chose modernizr you can use flexbox and table parallel and the browser choses to use the version it supports

Comment: Sorry! Your suggestion is still the best one in general. But in my specific case grahams workaround does exactly what I wanted to do and it's compatible downwards (besides the `:nth-child()`, but I can go around this because I have a fixed amount of items, just the text varies). Anyway, thanks again for your effort!

Comment: @HerrSerker, Yeah, you're right, and I know that. But I'm not feeling comfortable with making the layout depending on JavaScript.

Comment: @LinusCaldwell Why is that? You could use modernizr for 'graceful degredation' or 'progressive enhancement'

Answer (score 0):

A little CSS edited, take a look at please, if this what you want, [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pconline2046/3TUk8/1/)

```css
body
{
    position: relative;
    background: #bbbbbb;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

header
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 630px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
    background: black;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
}

nav ul,
nav li
{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav ul
{
    width: 200px;
}

nav ul li a
{
    display: block;
    padding: 1px;
    background: #0099ff;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li a:hover
{
    background: black;
}

nav li{
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    height: 25px;
    line-height:25px;
}
```

Comment: But now it's a vertical menu, not horizontal!

Comment: Thanks for your response. But unfortunately that's not what I want. As I mentioned, I want to have a horizontal menu. And floating the items like Lowkase suggested is not an option because I don't want to give the items a fixed width. They should take the space they need, so that I can have short and long item texts all resulting in the same width for the whole left menu part.

Answer (score 0):

While using absolute, every thing related/relating to that must be absolute in term of pixels.

I have updated fiddle, as your nav + logo .header + .nav:last-child were not totaling proper.

Fiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/3TUk8/2/

in other case you will have to do that

```css
nav ul
{
    display: table;
    background: #bbbbbb; /* that's what you see in webkit and same as bg color will hide it :) */
    list-style: none;
}
```

I hope this solve your problem :)

Comment: Thank you for your effort! Unfortunately there seems to be a misunderstanding. I didn't mean the "margin" around the logo. I meant the white gap WebKit browsers render right to the second last item. I updated my question to provide a comparison screenshot.

Comment: Have updated answer, pls refer last answer, make UL background same as body background that will hide the problem, webkit does not provide solution to this, one property for webkit is there `-webkit-column-gap:0em;` but that also not working. try if work on your side :)

Comment: :-) You're really trying to help me out. I appreciate it, thank you a lot! The problem is, in the final version there is a `background-image`, not just a color. So this won't work in my case, sorry. But again: I really thank you for your effort. You are great!

Comment: `ul{background:transparent}`
enjoy :)

Comment: Delicious :-) All your `background` workarounds would work in some other cases (unfortunately not in mine), so partly you're absolutely right. But even then, the left part of the menu is `2px` thinner than it should be. Yes, I'm a little bit like "Monk", so this is not acceptable for me... I would not be able to sleep. ;-) Anyway, thanks again very much!